# XPath expression to find <a> inside <tr>

Tags: xpath

What I need to find is the "Edit" link that coincides with the "Test Group" link.

I have tried:

```
//td[contains(text(),'Edit')]/..//a[text()='Test Group']
//td[contains(., "Edit")]/preceding-sibling::a
//*[contains(text(),'Edit')]//tr/td[contains(., 'Test Group')])[3]
```

Source HTML:

```
<td>
  <a class="hovsml" onclick="editGroup(5522); return false;" href="#">Edit</a>
</td>
<td>
   <a class="hovsml" onclick="removeGroup(5522,'Test Group'); return false;" href="#">Delete</a>
</td>
<td>
  <img id="groupText5522" width="16" vspace="0" border="0" hspace="0" height="16" onmouseout="hideGroupList('groupInfoDiv5522');" onmouseover="showGroupList('groupText5522','groupInfoDiv5522');" src="img/group_info.gif" style="position: relative;"/>
  <a class="hovsml" title="Test Group" onclick="popup('GroupInfo.php?id=5522','groupinfo',300,430); return false;" href="#">Test Group</a>
</td>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most robust approach is probably to start with all <tr>s that contain a "Test Group" link and find the "Edit" link from there:

```
tr[.//a[text()='Test Group']]//a[text()='Edit']
```

(Assuming all <td>s have a <tr> parent.)

Answer (score 0):

Start from the "Test Group" link, go up two levels, then look for the "Edit" link:

```
//a[text()='Test Group']/../../td/a[text()='Edit']
```

Comment: This also worked thanks a alot appreciate your time!